# Как отдать файл на скачивание, изменив его имя на новое, которое хранится в базе данных?

Tags: nginx

Помогите. Облазил весь инет, читал документацию, но никак не получается это сделать.

Сервер: nginx в связке php-fpm.

ЯП: php

Как я понял из общих положений, сделать можно разными способами, но мне видимо не хватает знаний и опыта в этом. 
Пока что у меня логика такая: юзер кликает на кнопку с урлом, nginx отрабатывает правило:

```
location ~ /files/id[a-z0-9]+/.+/[-0-9]+ {
    # тут должно быть что-то, какой-то запрос или редирект,
    # который перенаправит юзера по url с GET-параметром в качестве текущего имени файла,
    # которое он возьмет из самого url и в свою очередь отдаст PHP скрипту.
    # А скрипт уже сделает всю магию по переименованию файла и отправит нужные заголовки вида:
    # header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . $file);
    # header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    # header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
}
```

**Так вот, что же должно быть внутри этого location?**

Я прочел действительно  много статей, которые могли бы меня приблизить к решению, но я видимо сыплюсь на каких-то мелочах, пробовал и так и эдак, но мне фундаментальных знаний по серверам не хватает. Даже ошибки, которые видимо с точки зрения nginx и не ошибки вовсе, не логгируются. Не знаю, куда дальше копать.

Comment: [например](https://serverfault.com/q/861727/292034). но вызов интерпретатора для отдачи каждого файла — это ж дыра в производительности. гораздо эффективнее будет формировать html сразу с нужным вам именем файла.

Comment: Напишите конечную цель всего этого действия. Один и тот же файл с разными именами? Ерунда какая-то.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, там `X-Accel-Redirect`, это значит бек что-то делает, а потом говорит нжинксу: ну а теперь [отдай клиенту файл с диска](https://www.opennet.ru/base/net/nginx_x_accel.txt.html), это быстро (если файл не на беке он-лайн готовится).

Comment: @TotalPusher, нет. Суть в том, что я при загрузке файла в хранилище его переименовываю. Оригинальное имя сохраняю в бд, в хранилище файл лежит под временным именем.
Пользователю дается кнопка с прямой ссылкой на файл с временным именем. Я хочу, чтобы сервер кинул это имя пыху и уже пых переименовал файл и отдал его клиенту.

Comment: @TotalPusher Но отдаст его клиенту сам сервер, а имя изменится в этом заголовке. 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
Фактически, файл переименовывать даже не требуется, нужно просто подменить его имя при скачивании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл `site.ru.conf`:

```
server {
  # настройки сервера
  listen 8085;

  # логи
  error_log /var/log/site.ru-error.log info;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/site.ru-access.log combined;

  # Переписываем правило на свой скрипт, скрипт должен лежать в /var/www/site.ru/down.php,
  # это прописано в `location ~ \.php$`: `root`
  location ~ /files/id[a-z0-9]+/.+/[-0-9]+ {
    rewrite ^/files/(.*) /down.php?path=$1 last;
  }

  # правила обработки PHP, в данном случае php-fpm
  location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/site.ru;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
  }

  # статика
  location /downloads {
    root /var/www;
    # эта опция делает локейшн доступным только "внутри"
    internal;
  }


}
```

Файл `down.php`:

```
<?php
$uri = "/downloads/" . $_GET['path'];

// защита от ".."
$uri = str_replace("..", "", $uri);

// необходимое имя
$fileName = "мой-файл.xlsx";

// нужные заголовки, Nginx их передает в клиент
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s', $fileName));

// говорим Nginx: передать файл
header(sprintf('X-Accel-Redirect: %s', $uri));
```

Такой конфиг по адресу `http://localhost:8085/files/idfoo123/bar456/789-000` отдает на скачивание файл `/var/www/downloads/idfoo123/bar456/789-000` с именем `мой-файл.xlsx`.

Comment: Не уверен, что Content-Disposition с русскими буквами будет корректно работать во всех браузерах

Comment: @andreymal, браузеров много. В хроме и лисе, работает, и ладно. Браузеров становится все больше, можно либо поддерживать всех мамонтов, либо нет. Если есть решение для кириллицы, буду рад узнать.

Comment: Браузеров много, а стандарт один, который предписывает делать хитрое кодирование :) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-4.3

Comment: @andreymal, можете предоставить пример? Я этим вопросом занимался, но так и остановился на варианте "передаем как есть".

Comment: К сожалению не могу, мне повезло избегать наличия filename в моей практике) Да и на php я не пишу

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я разобрался намедни с директивой rewrite (неправильно ее готовил) и подправил ваш конфиг под себя.  
Ваш комментарий `# Переписываем правило на свой скрипт, скрипт должен лежать в /var/www/site.ru/down.php,
  # это прописано в location ~ \.php$: root` все расставил по своим местам)

Comment: @OlegFedorov, `(неправильно ее готовил)` - логи Nginx часто помогают выяснить, что происходит внутри. `nginx -T` показывает "собранную" конфигурацию + ошибки. К сожалению, у Nginx нет опции показа "каким путем пошел запрос" (у совсем другой программы - MTA Exim это есть, там пишутся правила, которые сработали, это реально очень круто помогает). Максимум, что можно придумать - это расставить [add_header](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) по конфигу, и затем смотреть, какие заголовки попали в ответ сервера.